# Delphi: Is Ms Jet 4.0 still a good choice to develop Desktop Database App?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado, jet

If I stick with Ms Jet 4.0 (Ms Access 2000-2002) to develop my desktop database program, do you think my app will become obsolete pretty fast? That is from using old db engine that will not be available in the latest windows OS like Windows 7?

Or Ms Jet 4.0 is still a safe bet?

I'm using D5 and ADO.

Please share your thoughts and opinion :)

Thanks!

Comment: Jet 4 is still part of Windows 7, as it's part of every version of Windows from Win2000 on. Where did you get the idea it's not part of Win7?

Answer (score 6):

Ms Jet drivers are not supported on x64 bit OS so IMHO you should no longer use it. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a great choice for an embedded database.

Comment: Of course 32-bit Jet 4 drivers are supported on 64-bit Windows, just like any 32-bit components are supported. What you can't do is create an x64 executable with 32-bit dependencies. But Office 2010 has made that problem solvable since you can use the 64-bit ACE, which is separately downloadable from MS.

Comment: I used Access for 7 good years. It was way better than most of the rest file server db solutions in terms of file size (not speed of access). It had lots of limitations but very powerful Db Explorer - Access itself. Until I switched to SQLite I was pretty happy with the Jet drivers. The only unresolvable problem was that some poorly written third party software can install older versions of the Jet driver dlls and ruin your soft. Check out SQLite instead.

Answer (score 5):

I would rather try Firebird Embedded. There are plenty of components to access this database (like Zeos) and Firebird Embedded is very easy to deploy (just copy few dlls and database file to output directory).

Answer (score 2):

Question was asked: "Is Ms Jet 4.0 still a good choice to develop Desktop Database App?"

The answer is No, it's a terrible choice.  It's old, outdated, and basically unsupported.

Comment: Jet 4 is still part of the OS. It's no longer in active development, so it's a really stable platform to develop against, and it makes your installer lighter-weight, since the db engine is already installed on every copy of Windows. If you want a more up-to-date and supported database engine that's just as easy to use, try the ACE (which also comes in 64-bit flavor). It will behave exactly the same as Jet 4 with legacy code (with the exception of the connect string, of course). However, it's no installed as part of the OS (though it's downloadable from MS and distributable).

Answer (score 1):

Jet 4.0, DAO 3.6 and ADO are part of the Windows operating system since Windows 2000 and is present in Windows 7.  I also don't see Microsoft removing those from the next version of Windows although I do't have any official or unoffical quotes on that.

Answer (score -1):

Since SQL Server Express is free, I think it would be quite stupid to use JET for a multi-user network based application.  It was only used in the past because there was no free version of SQL Server.

But if you want a simple database app that just runs on a single workstation then JET may well be an easy option considering ease of deployment etc.